# Square root of band matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

How can I find a square root of $\mathbf A = \mathbf B^\top \mathbf B$, where
$$
\mathbf B =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    -r & 1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & -r & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -r &1
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)
$$

To be more precise, I have to estimate $\boldsymbol \beta$ from the following regression problem:
$$
\mathcal N(\mathbf y \mid \mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta , \sigma ^2 \mathbf B^\top \mathbf B)
$$
given $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf X$. Let $\mathbf R = (\mathbf B^\top \mathbf B)^{\frac 12}$, then multiplying by $\mathbf R ^{-1}$:
$$
\mathcal N(\mathbf R ^{-1}\mathbf y \mid \mathbf R ^{-1}\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta , \sigma ^2 \mathbf I)
$$
we obtain simple linear regression problem.

Answer (score 2):

To find the square root of $A$ you can diagonalize it. In other words, you decompose $A = VDV^{-1}$, then compute $R= A^{1/2} = VD^{1/2}V^{-1}$. (Computing $D^{1/2}$ is fast since it's diagonal -- just the element-wise square root.)

Fortunately, $A$ is symmetric tridiagonal, so decomposing $A=VDV^{-1}$ is also computationally easy. (We have $A_{ii} = 1+r^2, A_{i+1,i}=A_{i,i+1}=-r \forall i\in[1,n-1]$ and $A_{nn}=1$.) If you store $A$ as a sparse matrix, Matlab should compute it quickly, and you could potentially try custom packages like trideigs for this specific case.

As an aside, for your problem you shouldn't actually invert $R$, but should just solve the system of equations.